# create save button in php file and execute some part of php code onclick it

Tags: php, button

I have js file that takes user input and call php file on submit.
The php file displays result of the entered data. I want to create "save button" to save these data in my database. "The save button should be in the php file"

I try for the button in my php file:

```
<?php

echo "<input type='button' value='Save Result'> </p>";
```

I try this code in the same php file to save the result:

```
$serverName = "Alaa";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"i2b2blast", "UID"=>"i2b2blast", "PWD"=>"demouser");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO BlastQueryDim (Query_ID, QuerySeq) VALUES ('Query 2', 'q')";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I want when I click the button to perform the saving code.

What I try and done successfully is:
creating a test button in js file and call php file onclick it. In this case, the result successfully saved in my database but, I want the save button to be in the php file.

Hope you getting my point.
Thanks a lot.

Edit 1:
One possible solution is to call another php file from my current php one. I don't like this because I should post a lot of parameters.
Anyway, in the first php file:

```
echo "<form action='saveResult.php' method='post' name='Post'>";
echo "<input name='Save' type='submit' value='Save Result'> </p>";
```

in the second php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Save'])) // If the submit button was clicked
{
$serverName = "Alaa";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"i2b2blast", "UID"=>"i2b2blast", "PWD"=>"demouser");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO BlastQueryDim (QueryID, QuerySeq) VALUES ('6', 'q')";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
}
echo "<script>alert('Saved');</script>";
```

This work successfully but, it navigate the page to saveResult.php page.
How can I execute the code of the second php "saveResult.php" in the background without redirect me?

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a form for your button.

```
<form method="post" name = "post">
 //rest
</form>
```

then in php code use this

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

 //execute code when button is clicked

}
```

**Important**

a form can be submitted in other ways (such as pressing Enter in a text box).
So Checking for a submit button field in the request is not that reliable.

**$_POST**
By just using this expression you can assert that:

1.The form is submitted via POST

2.At least one field has been submitted

that's why i prefer *request_method* instead of checking

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
//php code
}
```

Comment: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'), POST refer to form name or form method? because i have different form post in the same php page

Comment: in this case the method post/get we choose post

Comment: The result is saved to my database but, I did not click save button!

Comment: @Alaa it should only send information when button is clicked. I think rest of code might be wrong?